# SSH Tunneling works on terminal, but not on Python?

Tags: python, sql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I tried to do SSH tunneling to server from my computer terminal with the following code.

```
ssh -L 3306:192.168.0.xx:41xx -p 2220 root@xxx.85.63.xxx
```

Then I accessed the database inside (MySQL) with the following command.

```
mysql -u username -h 192.168.0.xx -P 41xx -p
```

And it worked. But when I tried to perform it using python, I couldn't make it work. I always got the following error.

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

My code so far is like below.

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('xxx.85.63.xxx', 2220),
         ssh_password="psswd",
         ssh_username="root",
         remote_bind_address=('192.168.0.xx', 41xx)) as server:

    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                           port=server.local_bind_port,
                           user='username',
                           passwd='passwd',
                           db='dbname')
```

What I want to do is access the database inside the server, and do the usual database manipulation process.

To be honest, I am not really familiar with SSH or SSH tunneling, so I am pretty much at lost here. Can someone point out what I am supposed to do please? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the port forwarding set up correctly.

This is a MySQL permission issue, which is indicated by the 'Access Denied'.

MySQL assigns permissions based on user@host. You're connecting as username@localhost, while the user is probably set up only as username@192.168.0.xx.

To see if I'm right, `try mysql -u username -h localhost -P 41xx -p` when you're logged on the SSH host. I think it might not let you in.

I'd take a look with `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';` and GRANT privileges to username@localhost or username@% or remove restrictive permissions.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It actually let me in using the `mysql -u username -h localhost -P 41xx -p` command. But once I am in, and I used the `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';` it says it doesn't work. The error is `There is no such grant defined for user 'usernamexxx' on host 'localhost'`. Idk what went wrong.

Comment: It might be there as `username@%`, a wildcard for the host name.

Take a look at the user table with `select * from mysql.user;` see if it makes sense. Remember to flush privileges after you grant.

Also, when you run the mysql command line client, that is on the remote host, right?

Oh, one more thing: maybe try `user='username@192.168.0.xx'` in Python. I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: One more thing on this. I forgot to point out that it appears you ran the mysql client on the remote host instead of your local. That doesn't tell you if the tunnel works or not. You might want to try running mysql client locally to connect to the tunnel, so you can verify that it's doing what you want it to do.

Comment: `select * from mysql.user;` does this command only work when you enter as root? Because I don't have access as root to the database and thus can't run this command. ` when you run the mysql command line client, that is on the remote host, right?` I believe so. I did the `user='username@192.168.0.xx'` and still got the access denied error.

Comment: `You might want to try running mysql client locally to connect to the tunnel`. You mean using some desktop SQL client? I tried it on windows (not my laptop) and it worked using SQL Heidi.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I didn't know what kind of machine you were establishing the tunnel from and if you had the command line client available. I really think this is a permissions issue, but it might help to make a connection with a good known mysql client than with new code. From the same machine where the Python code runs, to the same tunnel listening on local port 3306. If your laptop is where you set up the tunnel and where the Python script runs, try to run a client there. If it's a Mac or linux you can install the mysql command line client, on Windows, well you know that.

Comment: Just to get as close as possible to how the Python script is connecting, but with another client/tool.

Comment: I ran the python code on linux mint. `but it might help to make a connection with a good known mysql client than with new code.` I agreed with this one, but I need to run the python code because I want to connect it to another database and update it with the data in real time. I don't think that's possible using putty and some mysql client?

Comment: No need for sarcasm. I'm suggesting that you troubleshoot your tunnel and credentials with a known tool before moving on to the Python script, in an attempt to narrow down the issue.

Try the following command on your mint box: `mysql -u username -h localhost -P 3306 -p`

If this doesn't make sense, you might have to tell me a little more about your network setup. Where is your laptop, where is the mint box, where is the mysql server, to which machines do the edited ip addresses belong, and between which two machines does the tunnel run?

Comment: I wasn't actually being sarcastic. I was genuinely asking as I was confused here. Sorry if that came across that way. I think I figured out the problem, but still cannot find the solution. I can't even run 'mysql' command on my local terminal. I cannot login or run any mysql command. Even the simplest command like `sudo mysql -u root` or `sudo mysql -u root -p` wouldn't work. I guess the problem is on my own machine? I have reinstalled mysql, but the problem persisted, and I really have no idea what to do now.

Comment: Sorry, I think misunderstood you. 

Which machine is your local terminal, is that your laptop or desktop? Is it a Mac or Windows? What other machines are involved?